# Custom painting in DataGridView, strange visual appearence

Tags: c++, datagridview, command-line-interface, repaint

I'm working on an application that uses a datagridview to visualize some data. The data is logically structured four by four. And to visualize this, I want to paint a line/border each fourth row in the datagridview.

I have done this by writing the following RowPostPaint method (stripped of bulk code)

```
System::Void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(System::Object^  sender, Forms::DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs^  e) {

    A = ...

    Rectangle rowBorder  = dataGridView1->GetRowDisplayRectangle(e->RowIndex,true);

    if(A->ID % 4 == 0){
        e->Graphics->DrawLine(gcnew Pen(Drawing::Color::Black),(float)
        rowBorder.X ,(float)(rowBorder.Y + rowBorder.Height-2), (float) rowBorder.X +
        rowBorder.Width  ,(float) (rowBorder.Y + rowBorder.Height-2) );
    }
}
```

For some reason, the painting  gets corrupted (shows more lines than there should be, see picture) when I use the scrollbar or resize the window. Forcing a redraw by, for instance, by selecting the affected row makes the errornous line go away.

I have tried several tips (double buffering, clips etc) to fix this, but I haven't been able to do so yet. 
As you probably have figured out, I'm quite new to graphics/painting in c++/cli. 
Now I'm out of ideas, I hope you can come with some fresh ones

[image: Errornous painting]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by painting at the top of each row instead of at the bottom. The artifacts were created because I use the row height to determine where in the row to paint the line. (If the row at the bottom is partially displayed, the row height will also be affected.)